# Ajax request for each row in a table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html-table

I am looking to execute an ajax request for each row displayed from a table.

Any chance someone could show me some code how this is possible? I have searched Google but can't seem to find anything all. I am really looking for is to  fetch a result from a MySQL table.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>this should have ajax request</td><td>ajax result</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have the following code to request the data:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

but can't seem to work out how execute it for each row in the table.

Any help is very much appreciated.

So this is how I want it to work; I have a table of contacts displayed on a page and for each one displayed it will send and email and report back success, so basically onload of each row execute this. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please post whatever you tried in PHP code

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com just updated

Comment: What is working now and what is Not ?

Comment: You cannot do this (this way) using PHP. PHP is not able to do non blocking background requests like know from js/ajax for the page is parsed (sever-side) in complete before it is sent to the users browser. But you seem to by trying the complete wrong design concept to solve your problem I guess. Why not simply fetch the complete data using PHP and then just render it the way you want? (in table, row, what ever). If I am understanding you right your problem can be solved without any javascript.

Comment: ok so ill explain again, the table is a list of people subscribed to our newsletter i wish for it to send an email to each one and report back succes if its sent